# AS3 - How to access an object instance from a separate class

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5, flashdevelop

I have a game engine class that creates my main character instance and game border instance when the game is loaded like so:

```
public class Engine extends MovieClip
{
     var char:Char = new Char(stage);
     stage.addChildAt(char, 1);

     var border1:Border = new Border();
     stage.addChild(border1);

    }
```

I would like to access the variable border1 that was created in the Engine class inside of my Char class.  Is this possible, and if so, how would I do it?

I've tried changing the code so border1 is static like so

```
static var border1:Border = new Border();
```

But then I get

```
error 1012: The static attribute may be used only on definitions inside a class.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this a few ways.

```
1.  Create the border1 and char instances in reverse order and pass the border1 to the char instance to maintain a reference.

var border1:Border = new Border();
stage.addChild(border1);

var char:Char = new Char(stage, border1);
stage.addChildAt(char, 1);

// Char consructor

public function Char(target:DisplayObjectContainter, border:Border):void {
    ...
    this._border = border;
}

// Now you have a reference to the border1 instance within your char instance.
```

You could also do this without passing the border1 instance to the constuctor, and instead just add a method that sets this property.

```
public function setBorder(border:Border):void {
    this._border = border;
}

// OR

public function set border(border:Border):void {
    this._border = border;
}
```

Another option would be to make the Engine instance maintain a reference to the border and allow communication through the Engine instance. For example,

```
public class Engine extends MovieClip {

    public var char:Char;
    public var border1:Border;

    public function Engine():void {
        char = new Char(stage);
        stage.addChildAt(char, 1);

        border1 = new Border();
        stage.addChild(border1);
    }
```

Now, if the char instance has a reference to the engine instance, then the border instance can be referenced by `myEngineInstance.border1`.

Or you can make the border instance static.  Making it static would allow for code inside of the Char instance like:

```
Engine.border1.<whatever>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!  However, when I try to make the border instance static I get the error `1012: The static attribute may be used only on definitions inside a class.`

Comment: Sorry about that.  I tried to space out my response with the return key and it added the comment before I was ready.

Comment: So, you are trying to add this to the stage?  Read the error.  It is telling you the problem.  To make the instance static, it needs to be a member of a class.

Comment: Oh, I see -- I have it working now.  I had declared the variable in the Engine() function, when I should have declared it before it.  This was causing the problem and confusion as it was inside a class, but it was inside a function that was inside a class.  Apparently it needs to be inside a class, but outside a function for it to work.  Thanks again for all of the help!

Comment: No problem.  If my answer has solved your problem, you should mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark next to it.